# Would+verb, simple past, or present tense to express the subjunctive in relative clauses

Tags: conditional-constructions, relative-clauses, subjunctives

Is it grammatically correct to use **the simple present tense of a verb** and **the simple past tense of *to be*** in relative clauses to express the subjunctive mood?

Examples:

1. *He would be happy with a woman who **loves** him for who he is.*
2. *He would be happy with a woman who **were or was** with him for who he is.*

Can we also express the subjunctive by using **the simple past tense or *would+verb*** in 1 and **the simple present tense or *would+verb*** in 2, as in the examples below?

1a *He would be happy with a woman who **loved** him for who he is.*

1b *He would be happy with a woman who **would love** him for who he is.*

2a *He would be happy with a woman who **is** with him for who he is.*

2b *He would be happy with a woman who **would be** with him for who he is.*

Could you please explain what the correct usage is and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the present tense or past tense works.

> 1.- *He would be happy with a woman who **loves** him for who he is.*
>    2.- *He would be happy with a woman who **was** with him for who he is.*
>   3.- *He would be happy with a woman who **loved** for who he is.*

However, the subjunctive works with ***would + base form*** with the following expressions:

> 1.- ***I wish*** you wouldn't speak loudly.
>   2.- ***If only*** it would snow.

Note also that subjunctive mood applies for more cases like:

> 1.- *I hope it **works**.*
>   2.- *We'll go there unless it **rains**.*

As you can see, the present simple is involved to invoke it.